# Recommender system with time window

Tags: machine-learning, mahout-recommender

What would be procedure in item-item CF if I want to calculate probability or predict count of product purchases for an user in the next seven or ten days based on the purchasing history?

For example if user1 buys two breads this week, what is the probability he/she will buy the 2 breads after 7 days again.

I am thinking of a model where the user-item matrix contain number of purchases and item has feature parameter such as week number corresponding to the time of product purchases, but I am not sure how good this is.

Thanks a lot!